# Php get parameter from SEO URL

Tags: php, friendly-url

I have my seo url such as

> http://domain.com/product/export-grade-large-size-3-tier-organizer-shelf-and-non-woven-storage-box-with-cover-21665223

at the tail of string there is a number represented an id, which I need it for DB processing, how can I separate and get the last id? I cannot use explode because it may have long string parameter with 'dash'.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with:

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/product/export-your-url-with-21665223';
$id = substr($url, strrpos($url, '-') + 1);
echo $id;
```

Comment: @FooSK It will also work with that string.

Comment: Great works, thanks @Ryan